# Internet Explorer 11 - Declare Javascript variables in developer tools console

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, developer-tools

How can I create debug variables in IE11 developer tools console like in Chrome, for example?

I have tried

```
1) a = new String("latex");
2) var a = new String("latex");
```

For the first one I got a **Variable undefined in strict mode**
For the second one I got **undefined** and whenever I try to access variable "a" I get the error **'a' is undefined**

Comment: Nop, got the same message as in 2

Comment: I tried it like you said with var a = new String("xy") and can access the data with a.toString()

Comment: Works for me? http://imgur.com/G521Qaq

Comment: on what page you try it? you custom with customs scripts?

Comment: @greenhoorn you tried in internet explorer 11?

Comment: @luis_f Yes, I did..

Comment: @GrundyI am trying this on a page with custom scripts I made. I tried to do the same in google.com page and I could make it work. It seems it's related with my scripts...

Comment: check in your script where you use `'use strict';` about it on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Comment: it seems that since my scripts are defined with 'strict mode' I can't make these kinds of debug experiences like in Chrome. IE is such a good boy :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what kind of javascript you're into with this `new String("...")` syntax, but for what I know the modern javascript in most browsers can recieve string values into `var` type parameters, as well as many other basic types - i.e

`var a = "latex"`

**EDIT**:

Apperently there is something such as new String - my bad :)
As mentioned in the comments, you can access it via `<parameter name>.toString()` if you want to be able to access the properties; Just learnt that myself today. :)

More about js strings you can find
[here.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)

Comment: There is only one reason to use the new keyword. You can add properties :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
var a = 'latex';
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to access the variable in the same frame context it has been defined in? In the Console tab/area ... there is a dropdown field in the upper right corner (right to the log level filter and the clear log button). Variables/Objects only live in the frame context they have been created in. Also, when you created the debug variable while a debugger breakpoint was active, you created that variable in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar where I couldn't even declare variables but it was because I was paused on a breakpoint. Go figure.